# How to modify a sftp symlink

Tags: sftp, symlink

Creating a symlink via `sftp` is as easy like that:

```
symlink oldpath newpath
```

but how can I modify the symlink *newpath* afterwards to point to *anotherpath*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the symlink and create a new one pointing to the other path:

```
rm newpath
symlink anotherpath newpath
```

OpenSSH calls [`symlink()`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/sftp-server.c#L1270) function from standard C library, which does not have any possibility to overwrite the symlink.

Comment: sure this is the only way? i was hoping that there is something like the force flag we can use with ln like so: ln -f -s

Comment: No, there is no other way. See me edit (with reference to the source code).